# text in the same line under figure

Tags: plot

How can I modify the code that all words in the same line , i.e.
u=0.3230mm  in the same line

```
\begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \subfloat[$u = 0.3230 mm$  ]
.....
\end{figure}[h]
```

[image]

thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Without a complete MWE hard to tell but chances are that there is not enough space for the text.

Comment: @marmot ,i thinks how to solve space problem, i need beautiful results ...

Comment: And we need an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to be able to help you to get a beautiful result.

Comment: It looks like the width of each subfigure is too narrow to accommodate the text of its caption in one line.  If you can make the subfigures a bit wider, the problem should go away.

Comment: @barbarabeeton what is another option?

Comment: If the width of the subfigures can't be increased, some other possibilities are to (1) make the font of the caption smaller, (2) omit the identifying letter, or (3) increase the allowed width of the caption.  Any of those might require patching the package you're using, but you haven't identified the package.  Or, if you put braces around the `[=]` that will reduce the space, but there may still not be enough space.

Comment: ... and you could use micrometer which would save you one digit.

Comment: This would be easier if you didn't use \subfloat.

Comment: @JohnKormylo why not using \subfloat???

Comment: Subfloat automatically adjusts the width to match the image, which in this case is too small.  You can still specify a larger width using \makebox.  OTOH, subfigure (subcaption package) requires you to specify the width, although one can measure the width of the image using a savebox and use that.

Answer (score 1):

the following *mwe*:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
\subfloat[$u = \SI{0.3230}{mm}$]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\linewidth]{example-image-duck}}
\hfill
\subfloat[$u = \SI{0.3392}{mm}$]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\linewidth]{example-image-duck}}
\hfill
\subfloat[$u = \SI{0.3781}{mm}$]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\linewidth]{example-image-duck}}
\hfill
\subfloat[$u = \SI{0.4541}{mm}$]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\linewidth]{example-image-duck}}
    \caption{Figures \dots}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

gives:

[image]

however, you not provide any information about your document layout (consequently we dot know what is your problem), so we don't know, if in your document you will obtain the same result ...

Comment: I would have used `\makebox[0.24\linewidth]{...}` with smaller images.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, why? you mean in case, when natural width of images are smaller than `0.24\linewidth`?.

Comment: Yup, since that is the case with the Mystery Wonder Example.

Comment: @Zarko why I have to use \usepackage{siunitx}?

Comment: @JohnKormylo I don't want to change figure size ..........

Comment: @ABCDEMMM, you not need to use `siunitx`. however, it is design for writing physical quantities on consistent way, i.e. that the combined mathematical meaning of the
number–unit combination is clear.

Comment: @ABCDEMMM, any news if my proposition work fr you? we still not have any information about your document layout, used fonts etc. please provide this information.